# ListBox showing collection name instead of value

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, windows-phone-8.1

Working with C# on a Windows Phone 8.1 project, I'm using SQLite to store some remote connection data, like IP, Name and Port, for a remote control of MPC.

The XAML has a ListBox element and it should show in each item the connection IP, but instead it is showing the full namespace of it and no valid value.

I may not understood yet how databinding works with Windows Phone and any direction will be welcome. Below, classes and the XAML:

### Models.Connection.cs

```
namespace RemotyMPC81.Models
{
    class Connection
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        private string _Host;
        public string Host
        {
            get
            {
                return this._Host;
            }
            set
            {
                this._Host = value;
            }
        }

        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Port { get; set; }


        public async static Task<ObservableCollection<Connection>> FetchAllAsList()
        {
            var rawList = await DatabaseManagement.ConnectionDb().Table<Connection>().ToListAsync();
            ObservableCollection<Connection> connections = new ObservableCollection<Connection>();

            foreach (Connection connection in rawList){
                connections.Add(connection);
            }

            return connections;
        }

        public async static Task Insert(Connection connection)
        {
            await DatabaseManagement.Insert(connection);
        }
    }
}
```

### Views.Connections.ListPage.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="LstConnection" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="486" Margin="10,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="380" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListViewItem>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Host, Mode=OneWay}" Width="380" Height="39"></TextBlock>
        </ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

### Views.Connections.ListPage.cs

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
    /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Connection> connections = await Connection.FetchAllAsList();

        LstConnection.ItemsSource = from conn in connections select conn;
    }
```

[image: Emulator Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You placed a *ListViewItem* directly in your ListBox. What you actually wanted to do was to set the *ItemsTemplate*

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.ItemsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock ... />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

Comment: Not sure if ItemTemplate or Item**s**Template... (No VS arround).

Comment: It is ItemTemplate, but soon I put that on code, VS already told me. Thank you. For further explanation, when I need to bind values I always have to declare it as `<ListView.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate></></>`? I mean, What is the difference from the `<ListViewItem>`?

Comment: ListViewItem is the *element* that is created for each entry in your list. If you don't use an ItemsSource, you can just manually put ListViewItems in there and put content in.

Comment: With your code, there was an empty item at the first position of the ListView, that did not show anything, because the binding did not find a valid value. You should have seen a binding error at runtime in the console too.